# "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'property' of undefined" when loading style with mapbox

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I am using mapbox-gl-js to render a map on my website. I made a map style in mapbox studio, also using other tilesets. I recently updated these (quite big) tilesets and changed some styling. In mapbox studio, the style worked perfectly well, but when I try to see the map on my website (which didn't change), I get several errors like "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined" (or with other properties), and the map doesn't render.

I already checked the token and the style address, but I guess the problem is my map style... Here is its URL :

mapbox://styles/clemapbox/cjml1byyjq6jt2rni6wbjn3lt

Here's a minimal code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.45.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
        <title>MINIMAL TEST</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <section id='map' style="width:500px;height:500px;"></section>

        <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.45.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
        <script>
            mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiY2xlbWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNqOHVsbjdpdDBxM2wyd3JwcnVjZGtsZmsifQ.cv3w8BmCJAy0f0YF1ZFSTA';
                var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
                    container: 'map',
                    style: 'mapbox://styles/clemapbox/cjml1byyjq6jt2rni6wbjn3lt',
                });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If the style is working in Studio, then it should be just fine (as Studio relies on GL JS under the hood to do a lot of its map rendering). Can you include an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your GL JS implementation so that the community can better help you troubleshoot?

Comment: Yes but I can use my code to display other styles... and it worked before that. Anyway, here is a minimal code :

Comment: Thank you for the example! I see the issue and will post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here appears to be an incompatibility with your style and the version of GL JS that you are using. Specifically, because your style is using the `text-radial-offset` style property which is not supported by GL JS until +v0.54.0.

When I update the version of GL JS your example is using, I am able to produce the expected result:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.54.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
        <title>MINIMAL TEST</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <section id='map' style="width:500px;height:500px;"></section>

        <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.54.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
        <script>
            mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiY2xlbWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNqOHVsbjdpdDBxM2wyd3JwcnVjZGtsZmsifQ.cv3w8BmCJAy0f0YF1ZFSTA';
                var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
                    container: 'map',
                    style: 'mapbox://styles/clemapbox/cjml1byyjq6jt2rni6wbjn3lt',
                });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any easy way to check for which client side library is compatible with your style is via the settings drop down in Studio:

[image: studio screenshot]

---

⚠️ disclaimer: I currently work for Mapbox ⚠️

Comment: I couldn't find where in my style I used this property, but I changed the version of mapbox to the lastest one in my script and it worked. This should have been the first thing to do... Well thank you very much !